# Wampserver doesn't bear php code with regex

Tags: php, regex, wampserver

Editing the whole question as i managed to narrow it down. This is the code

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$file = file_get_contents("oui.txt");
preg_match_all("/[0-9ABCDEF]{6}(?=(?:.*?\s*)*CHINA)/", $file ,$out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($out);
?>
```

This code make wampserver 2.3 to show *This webpage is not available* but when i change the regex to any simpler for instance only `[0-9ABCDEF]{6}` in this very code, it run smoothly.

When this error ocurr the apache_error.log file says this:

```
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Win32) PHP/5.4.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Server built: Aug 24 2012 11:30:00
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2376
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Child 2376: Child process is running
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Child 2376: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Child 2376: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:56 2014] [notice] Child 2376: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Don't know if it have anything to do with the fact that it also shows errors when i try to access any folder;

```
[Sun Mar 30 17:36:30 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://localhost/anyfolder/
```

I have no skype.
Thank you very much

Comment: What is the exact error (appearing in the logs) ?

Comment: What is the content of oui.txt, at least a significant extract?

Comment: [Here](http://regexr.com/?38khn) is the link, the error appearing is [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iIopt.png)

Comment: This is a PHP regex issue and not related to WAMPServer in any specific way. So I changed the title to attract a better class of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be simplified with:

```
preg_match_all(
    "/[0-9ABCDEF]{6}(?=.*CHINA)/",
    $file,
    $out,
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER|PCRE_DOTALL
);
```

If preg_match entered some weird loop, this should solve the issue.

The `PCRE_DOTALL` makes the `.` aware of linebreaks as well.

Comment: Hi Robin, There're some brake lines as well before _CHINA_, have a look at the link above please.

Comment: Didn't thought about that indeed. So your `\s` was just to match newlines? There's actually a flag you can set so that the `.` matches also newlines, I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a wampserver's bug on Windows XP